# onLocationChanged method still running in different Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-context

I have an activity which uses onLocationChanged method and upon performing a parse query it makes a toast. It works fine. However, when I go to another activity (it's a maps activity), if I change the coordinates (I'm using an emulator) the toast pops up. I would like to know why the onLocationChanged method is still running. I thought it may be due to context, but I specified the activity in the context field.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) DriverChoicesActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            final ParseGeoPoint parseGeoPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null && objects.size() > 0) {
                        for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                            object.put("driverLocation", parseGeoPoint);
                            object.saveInBackground();
                            Toast.makeText(DriverChoicesActivity.this, "User found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            updateRequestList(location);

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
};
```

All that is within onCreate of the original activity (DriverChoicesActivity.class). The other activity (DriverMapActivity.class) has no code in it apart from getting the intent from this activity to collect some latitude and longitude points. Here is the code which makes the intent (also within onCreate)

```
requestListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
requestListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (requestLatitude.size() > position && requestLongitude.size() > position) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DriverChoicesActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Location getLastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (getLastKnownLocation != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DriverMapActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("requestLatitude", requestLatitude.get(position));
                        intent.putExtra("requestLongitude", requestLongitude.get(position));
                        intent.putExtra("driverLatitude", getLastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
                        intent.putExtra("driverLongitude", getLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
});
```

I assume my problem is with context somehow. If someone could be kind enough to explain.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add:

`locationManager.removeUpdates(listener)`;

Before move to next Activity.

and

```
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
```

on the top, under class declaraction